# How much time does it take to update the monthly ranking of a Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, users

I have gained around 30 reputation points today, but when I open my profile it still shows me the old reputation count and the old ranking for monthly ranks. I want to know how much time it will take to fully update my ranking with the new reputation count.

Comment: I guess each UTC time change

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think you mean each UTC day/date change :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey well, when we cross midnight each day :p

Answer (score 1):

Since these types of calculations require a decent amount of DB processing, they are run in batches at the statistical low in bandwidth for the servers.

It will not update until that script runs, and the script execution time is subject to change. At present, the script runs daily at 03:00 UTC. However, not all calculations run each time the script runs, some run weekly, monthly, or waffles.

On exceedingly rare occasions, the script times out, and can take a day or two to notice and fix.

In general though, the answer to "how much time does it take to update x" is worst case 24 hours. In this specific case, it more than likely will update the next time the script runs ( in 5 and a half hours from now ). If not then, then probably at down time on the weekend since the rep league calculations can be costly.